# How to pull actual values from foreign id when an array of ids is returned?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am making an e-commerce site where the person can make an offer for the product. And I want to display all the offers on product at a place where I get the product.After that want to get the information about the user who made the offer and the parent offer in the same query.

I am getting the product like this

```
`public function show(Product $product)
    {
        // return response()->json($product);

        return new SingleProductResource($product);
    }`
```

The SingleProductResource returns the following

```
`public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'            => $this->id,
            'title'         => $this->title,
            'description'   => $this->description,
            'type'          => $this->type,
            'images'        => $this->images,
            'status'        => $this->status,
            'owner'         => $this->user,     
            'offers'        => $this->offers,
        ];
    }`
```

Offers returns an array like this

```
`"offers": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "user_id": null,
                "product_id": 1,
                "offer_amount": "3",
                "parent_id": 2,
                "created_at": "2022-11-12T07:54:10.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-11-12T07:54:10.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "user_id": 1,
                "product_id": 1,
                "offer_amount": "3",
                "parent_id": 2,
                "created_at": "2022-11-12T08:01:29.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-11-12T08:01:29.000000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "user_id": null,
                "product_id": 1,
                "offer_amount": "3",
                "parent_id": null,
                "created_at": "2022-11-12T08:01:56.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-11-12T08:01:56.000000Z"
            }
]`
```

But I want to get the user information directly in this query.
I cannot do this(see comment below) inside the resource as $this->offers returns an array.

```
`return [
            'id'            => $this->id,
            'title'         => $this->title,
            'description'   => $this->description,
            'type'          => $this->type,
            'images'        => $this->images,
            'status'        => $this->status,
            'creator'       => $this->user,
            'offers'        => $this->offers->user, //this
        ];`
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to trim your $product in some way. For example

```
$products = Product::leftJoin('offers', 'products.id', 'offers.product_id')
           ->where('user_id')
           ->where('products.id', $product['id'])
           ->get();
return new SingleProductResource::collection($products);
```